# Cache write misses

Tags: cpu-cache

I've been using Intel Pin tool to perform analysis of cache miss rates of a parallel application in multi-level caches, using one of the examples [allcache.cpp](https://github.com/jingpu/pintools/blob/master/source/tools/Memory/allcache.cpp), the results differentiate load and write misses, and the miss rates of each one vary significantly in L1, load miss rates of 20% vs store misses 90%.

Why can be such difference between each type?

Comment: *read something not written yet* (/ *recently*) vs *write something not read yet*?

Comment: Why do you think there *couldn't* be such a difference?

Comment: @D.W. I've been thinking about it but I can't see a reason, the program is performing about the same number of reads and writes, even slightly more reads, so I expected the miss rate to be also more or less similar for reads and writes.